# Constructing piecewise symbolic function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, piecewise

I am trying to generate a piecewise symbolic function in Matlab. The reason it has to be symbolic is I want to be able to integrate/differentiate the function afterwards and/or insert actual values. I have the following function:

```
x^3/6   ->   0 < x <= 1
(1/6)*(-3*x^3+12*x^2-12x+4)   ->   1 < x <= 2
(1/6)*(3*x^3-24*x^2+60x-44)   ->   2 < x <= 3
(1/6)*(4-x)^3   ->   3 < x <= 4
0   ->   otherwise
```

For example, I want to put this function in a variable (let's say f) and then call

```
int(diff(f, 1)^2, x, 0, 4) % numbers could be different
```

and get the (scalar) result 2/3.

I tried various things, involving the piecewise() function and symbolic comparisions, but nothing worked... can you help? :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One option is to use the [`heaviside`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/heaviside.html) function to make each equation equal zero outside of its given range, then add them all together into one equation:

```
syms x;
f = (heaviside(x)-heaviside(x-1))*x^3/6 + ...
    (heaviside(x-1)-heaviside(x-2))*(1/6)*(-3*x^3+12*x^2-12*x+4) + ...
    (heaviside(x-2)-heaviside(x-3))*(1/6)*(3*x^3-24*x^2+60*x-44) + ...
    (heaviside(x-3)-heaviside(x-4))*(1/6)*(4-x)^3;
double(int(diff(f, 1)^2, x, 0, 4))

ans =

    0.6667
```

Another alternative is to perform your integration for each function over each subrange then add the results:

```
syms x;
eq1 = x^3/6;
eq2 = (1/6)*(-3*x^3+12*x^2-12*x+4);
eq3 = (1/6)*(3*x^3-24*x^2+60*x-44);
eq4 = (1/6)*(4-x)^3;
total = int(diff(eq1, 1)^2, x, 0, 1) + ...
        int(diff(eq2, 1)^2, x, 1, 2) + ...
        int(diff(eq3, 1)^2, x, 2, 3) + ...
        int(diff(eq4, 1)^2, x, 3, 4)

total =

2/3
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Although it's mentioned in the question that the [`piecewise`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/piecewise.html) function didn't work, [Karan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41991115/52738) suggests it does, at least in newer versions. The documentation for `piecewise` currently says it was introduced in R2016b, but it was clearly present much earlier. I found it in the documentation for the [Symbolic Math Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/index.html) as far back as R2012b, but the calling syntax was different than it is now. I couldn't find it in earlier documentation for the Symbolic Math Toolbox, but it did show up as a function in other toolboxes (such as the Statistics and Spline Toolboxes), which explains its mention in the question (and why it didn't work for symbolic equations at the time).

Comment: @Jonas: Thanks. The `12x` needed to be fixed too.

Comment: Regarding _as far back as R2012b_, you might be referring to the MuPAD piecewise function, which is a different interface from the Symbolic Math Toolbox. For the SMT, it was introduced in R2016b. Sorry about the confusion with the toolboxes. Let me know if I can answer any other questions.

Comment: @Karan: I see now. It first shows up in the documentation in R2012b ([*MathWorks login required*](https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2012b/symbolic/mupad_ref/piecewise.html?searchHighlight=piecewise)), but only as a function accessible through a MuPAD interface, not MATLAB itself. The newest version in R2016b can be called directly from MATLAB.

Answer (score 3):

Starting R2016b, use the [piecewise](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/piecewise.html) function

```
syms x
y = piecewise(x<0, -1, x>0, 1)

y =
piecewise(x < 0, -1, 0 < x, 1)
```

For this case:

```
syms x
f = piecewise( ...
0< x <=1, x^3/6, ...
1 < x <= 2, (1/6)*(-3*x^3+12*x^2-12*x+4), ...
2 < x <= 3, (1/6)*(3*x^3-24*x^2+60*x-44), ...
3 < x <= 4, (1/6)*(4-x)^3, ...
0)

f =
piecewise(x in Dom::Interval(0, [1]), x^3/6, x in Dom::Interval(1, [2]), - x^3/2 + 2*x^2 - 2*x + 2/3, x in Dom::Interval(2, [3]), x^3/2 - 4*x^2 + 10*x - 22/3, x in Dom::Interval(3, [4]), -(x - 4)^3/6, 0)

int(diff(f, 1)^2, x, 0, 4)
ans =
2/3
```

Comment: Explanations for the downvotes would be helpful, since this is the recommended method to create piecewise functions in Symbolic Math Toolbox.

Comment: I'm guessing the downvotes were because your old example didn't match the question at all; your new example should remedy that. Also, the update in my answer may be of interest. People may have downvoted because the question specifically mentions `piecewise` not working, which it actually didn't at the time it was asked, but does now as you show.

Comment: Fair enough. I hope my edited answer is useful. Happy to answer any other questions.